# File not found during compilation

Tags: qt

What is wrong with the code bellow?  When I compile it I get a warning that file not found.  Something is invalid.  I'm probably making a few mistakes here.  I think the problem is perhaps with the way I inherit from QWidget.

```
   #include <QtGui/QApplication>
    #include "filedialogs.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        FileDialogs w;
        w.openFile();

        return 0;
    }
```

---

```
#ifndef FILEDIALOGS_H
#define FILEDIALOGS_H

    #include <QWidget>
    class QFileDialog;

    class FileDialogs : public QWidget
    {

    public:
        FileDialogs(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~FileDialogs();

        void openFile();
    };

    #endif // FILEDIALOGS_H
```

---

```
#include <QFileDialog>
#include "filedialogs.h"

FileDialogs::FileDialogs(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

FileDialogs::~FileDialogs()
{

}

void FileDialogs::openFile()
{
  QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
      this,
      tr("Open Document"),
      QDir::currentPath(),
      tr("Document files (*.doc *.rtf);;All files (*.*)") );

  if( !filename.isNull() )
  {
    qDebug( filename.toAscii() );
  }
}
```

---

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-07-29T19:06:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

TARGET = exX
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        filedialogs.cpp

HEADERS  += filedialogs.h
```

Comment: What file is not found, what is invalid?

Comment: QtCreator isn't specific about this.  My guess is that it doesn't like something in FILEDIALOGS_H.  The other strange thing is that it does compile despite the warning and does seem to work.  Then if I compile again, it does not complain until I change something in the src code. Strange.  Something must be wrong in the code that I'm not seeing.

Comment: The exact message is:  "No relevant classes found. No output generated."  (filedialogs.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is emitted by the MOC compiler. You are missing the Q_OBJECT macro. Put it in your class declaration like this:

```
class FileDialogs : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    ....
```

Comment: Hmmm, that got rid of the warning. Thanks.  I'm a tad confused now, why do I need the Q_OBJECT macro when I'm not declaring any signals or slots?

Comment: There are a number of reasons beyond those ones that Qt documentation never seems to go into detail about and they usually just end up saying, put it in anyway. For the sake of 8 characters, I put it in every Qt subclass I write because I almost always end up doing something eventually that needs it. It's one of those things I've decided not to pour the energy into figuring out until I decide I want to start modifying the Qt library :) If I were to guess though, I would suspect the tr() macro.

Comment: Fair, enough. Thanks again.  Would you say that my code other than the missing Q_OBJECT macro is OK? No glaring ridiculousness?  I'm still new to Qt and C++.

Comment: Looks like a fine start to me. First timers don't usually start out with translatable strings so you're ahead of the game :)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about the design pattern (If I can call it that).

Answer (score 0):

I know this Question is very old. But in my case it was another problem.
I had to include the path of the headers manually in the .pro file.

```
INCLUDEPATH += src/subdir
```